# Delphi XE8 + SDL2 + Android

Tags: android, delphi, sdl2

Удалось ли кому-нибудь подружить этот зверинец?

У меня возникли проблемы с запуском именно под Андроид.
Под каждую версию Андроида собирается своя libSDL2.so, я собрал тестовую
программу от SDL "testgles" (c++ исходники), запустил ее на Android 2.3 - работает. Взял и из пакета libSDL2.so и подключил библиотеку к Delphi Multi-device проекту, при запуске на телефоне получаю следующую ошибку SDL:

> Application didn't initialize properly, did you include SDL_main.h in the file containing your main() function?

Нормальных заголовочных файлов SDL2 для Pascal под Android просто нет.

При компиляции проекта под Win32 и подключении библиотеки SDL2.dll - все работает прекрасно.

Порядок действий таков:

1. Динамически загружаем библиотеку в зависимости от платформы: .DLL или .SO
2. Связываем адреса функций из библиотеки.
3. Запускаем SDL_Init() и потом SDL_Quit();

***update***

Вообщем суть в том, что под Win32 платформу мы имеем такую связку EXE + DLL (где основное приложение запускает библиотеку), отсюда и удачная инициализация и все такое. Под Android мы имеем более сложную связь JavaApp + libApp.so + libSDL2.so (где собственно JavaApp - основной класс обеспечивающий запуск нативного функционала из libApp.so, а сама библиотека SDL подгружается в нативную libApp.so).

Как подступится к "тельцу" FireMonkey Java-Classes в Delphi XE8 не нашел. :(

Вывод: видимо не судьба.